# angular.js directives in different modules

Tags: angularjs

I am confused. If I can use `ng-app` only once per page how can I use directives that sit in different modules, in different .js files. Look:

```
<script src='mainModule.js'/>
<script src='secondModule.js'/>
<body ng-app='mainModule'>
   <my-thingy/>
   <div>
      <other-thingy/>
   </div> 
</body>

mainModule.js:
   angular.module("mainModule",[]).directive("myThingy",function(){ ... })

secondModule.js:
   angular.module("secondModule",[]).directive("otherThingy",function(){ ... })
```

So, how do I now point to the secondModule on the page, without referencing it from mainModule.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution to bootstrap several angular modules on a page programmatically ( [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) ).

You have to remove `ng-app` attribute from html.

Define several modules:

```
var app1 = angular.module('myApp1', []);

var app2 = angular.module('myApp2', []);

app1.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'App1';
});

app2.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'App2';
})
```

And then in index.html do:

```
  <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <!-- Module 1 -->
    <div id="myApp1">
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Module 2 -->
    <div id="myApp2">
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap modules -->
    <script>
      angular.element(document).ready(function() {
          angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myApp1'), ['myApp1']);
          angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myApp2'), ['myApp2']);
     });
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Here is a working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UowJpWYc1UDryLLlC3Be?p=preview) with this solution.

Comment: I don't think it is a good solution as it would start 2 completely separated AngularJS applications. On top of this it disallow some use cases (for example, what if I would like to use 2 directives, one within another?

Comment: can you somehow reuse a directive without binding it to any module?

Comment: Actually not. And it's the weakness @pkozlowski.opensource pointed. Another way he described in his answer

Comment: @Agzam: Yes you can write directives that aren't bound to any custom modules. They're still bound to some module which is `ng` module. These directives would be accessible on any custom app module page as well as on those that just set `<html ng-app>` without specifying any particular application module.

Answer (score 50):

@Agzam, just **create a third, top-level, application module that will have dependencies on your sub-modules containing directives**:

```
<script src='mainModule.js'/>
<script src='secondModule.js'/>
<script>
  angular.module('app', ['mainModule', 'secondModule'])
</script>
<body ng-app='app'>
   <my-thingy/>
   <div>
      <other-thingy/>
   </div> 
</body>
```