# How to run two separate Angular js apps in the same page

Tags: angularjs

New to Angular. I feel like I'm missing something obvious: Shouldn't I easily be able to run to separate AngularJs apps (modules) in the same html page? Something like this:

```
  <section ng-app="HelloWorldApp" ng-controller="HelloWorldController">
    Hello {{name}}!
  </section> 
  <br />
  <section ng-app="MyNameIsApp" ng-controller="MyNameIsController">
    My Name is {{FirstName}} {{LastName}}!
  </section>
```

Javascript:

```
var HelloWorldApp = angular.module('HelloWorldApp', []);
HelloWorldApp.controller('HelloWorldController', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

var MyNameIsApp = angular.module('MyNameIsApp', []);
MyNameIsApp.controller('MyNameIsController', function($scope) {
  $scope.FirstName = 'John';
  $scope.LastName = 'Smith';
});
```

This only runs the first module, while the second doesn't appear to do anything. I want to do this so that I can build reusable, encapsulated directives for multiple pages that don't have to name their modules the same thing.

Live Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/cE6i3ouKz8SeQeA5h3VJ

---

We ended up building [small hierarchy of modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15644492/125275), however my original question can done, with just a bit of work (see below).

Comment: Please take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641730/angular-js-directives-in-different-modules/15642327#15642327  and also consider another one http://stackoverflow.com/a/15644492/637740 . Usualy second fits best

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It is possible, but it requires a little bit coding by hand. You need to bootstrap the angular apps on your own. Don't worry, it is not that complicated

- Do not add `ng-app` attributes in your HTML
- Make sure you can fetch the DOM elements holding the app
- When DOM is loaded you need to start the apps on your own: `angular.bootstrap( domElement, ['AppName']);`

Fork of you plunker which works: http://plnkr.co/edit/c5zWOMoah2jHYhR5Cktp

Comment: Works great, thanks! AngularJS also has a documentation for this, FYI: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: @GrahamJRoy no problem ;-)

Comment: What would happen if there 2 apps are nested? For example, there is a main app taking up the whole page and a mini app inside the page? Would this function?

Answer (score 7):

According to the Angular [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp) for ngApp:

> Use this directive to auto-bootstrap an application. Only one
> directive can be used per HTML document. The directive designates the
> root of the application and is typically placed at the root of the
> page.

Seems it's by design.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify any nested apps in the module def of the main one.

```
angular.module("myapp", ['statusapp', 'tickerapp']).controller(....
```

and in a separate file, you have the other apps defined. We're using a template engine which hides some of this, but you'll end up with HTML that contains nested ng-apps and javascript for each one that defines the module/controller. The code above is the trick to getting more than one bootstrapped.