# Can you dynamically load modules in Angular?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have an angular app with two distinct sections to it. Each section belongs to a type of user. There are some commonalities but for the most part rather different. For example:

```
/receptionist
    - View Diary
    - Answer Phone
    - Make Tea 
/ceo
    - View Diary
    - Announce Earnings
    - Strategize
```

Both the ceo and the receptionist need the functionality for viewing the diary. I was thinking wanting to change the modules loaded (and the routing) depending on who logged in.

```
if (user.type === 'receptionist') {
    app = angular.module('receptionistApp', ['diary', 'phone', 'tea']);
else {
    app = angular.module('ceoApp', ['diary', 'earning', 'strategy']);
}
```

I am wanting to do this because there is some overlap, but not a lot. And each app is actually quite big.

I am not wanting to achieve anything security wise here. Each app will have different types of users and roles. Those will be secured through WebApi. I just wanting to avoid loading all of the modules when 45% of them will be of no interest to the other app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Also, (and you probably won't need this) you can load modules [even more dynamically](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap), and initialize AngularJS yourself instead of having it load instantly. You can remove the ng-app directive, and do a manual initialization.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.module('myApp', []);
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Comment: nice , and what about plugging modules while run-time , i mean after app' bootstrapping/initialization ?

Comment: Not entirely sure about that, i know you can do [bootstrap on different elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342603/how-to-run-two-separate-angular-js-apps-in-the-same-page?rq=1) as you can ng-app on different elements, it would probably depend on what the module would do but i doubt its supported by default