# How to run 2 AngularJS apps on the same domain?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I have 2 apps. A homepage app, and a dashboard app. Now I run both apps on the same domain. The default app, homepageApp, is run first. When homepageApp links to dashboardApp, it should run this app. How to config this?

Comment: there is an answer for this question, please check with this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342603/how-to-run-two-separate-angular-js-apps-in-the-same-page]    or you can see the angular js docs FYI : [https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap]

Answer (score 0):

If it is within a same domain, then i think you can achieve it using the same app. It just that you need to define the proper controller to redirect the different page.

Comment: Looks like it has been answered before, have a look at it. Hope it helps.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342603/how-to-run-two-separate-angular-js-apps-in-the-same-page

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are modules: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

These will allow you to have your app depend on two different sets of controllers/filters/directives/etc.  For example:

**html**

```
<html ng-app="newApp">
<body>
  <div ng-controller="newAppController">
    {{ greeting }}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="homepageController">
    {{ greeting }}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="dashboardController">
    {{ greeting }}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**js**

```
angular.module("homepageApp", [])
  .controller("homepageController", function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = "Hello Homepage";
  });

angular.module("dashboardApp", [])
  .controller("dashboardController", function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = "Hello Dashboard";
  });

angular.module("newApp", ["homepageApp", "dashboardApp"])
  .controller("newAppController", function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = "Hello World";
  });
```