# How do I combine two AngularJS apps as modules of a main app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

Another basic AngularJS question. I have two AngularJS apps, `slider.js` (AngularUI) & `json.js`.

#### [Here's `slider.js` as a Plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/zySArHvqZgJHHMq4DBL1?p=preview)

#### [Here's `json.js` as a Plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/lVh7sm2qAVsdxk4MarJw?p=preview)

I want them both to run on a page. In fact, I want to use them together: I want to render sliders within my JSON renders. What is the best way to do this? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641730/angular-js-directives-in-different-modules/15644492#15644492) suggests creating a Main app & calling these both within it. Is that a good solution for when I want the functionality of both apps in the same place on the page, or should I be working on "combining" the apps- and how would one go about doing that?

My not-working attempt so far is here:

#### [Plunkr of the two apps combined, not working](http://plnkr.co/edit/V1ct7J5OiSzuL3zJUGZq?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the slider as dependent of myapp then use myapp in the page declaration, so that myApp will have all elements(directives/controllers/filters etc) added in slider app also.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.slider']);
```

then

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ltUxDe8enuh4xDUSit4o?p=preview)