# How to combine angularjs modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an angularjs application with codeigniter(PHP framework), I have 3 modules, each module for each client. So I have created cars.js for car details, cellphones.js for cellphone details and home.js for home details. These 3 js are different from each other.

I just want to compare the total estimation price of selected items. I tried with angularjs $cookies but not worked for me. Here I have my code as follow.

To make it very easy to understand I will add one simple basic controller to each app with some row data. Each JSON array has price, I am adding a checkbox to add to estimate, whenever user clicks on it it should be added to estimated list and the total amount should get changed accordingly. So this is the basic example I am showing just to understand how to combine angularjs apps and how to keep added items.

Here is my js code

```
home.js
var app1 = angular.module("HomeApp",['uiSlider','ui.bootstrap']);
app1.controller('HomeCtrl', function( $scope,$http,$q,$location,$window,$routeParams,$modal, $log, $timeout) {
$scope.homerating=[{"home_info_id":"94","avg":"3","price":"4900"},
                   {"home_info_id":"119","avg":"4","price":"200"},
                   {"home_info_id":"95","avg":"4.5","price":"500"}];
});

cellphone.js1
var app2 = angular.module("CellphoneApp",['uiSlider','ui.bootstrap']);
app2.controller('CellphoneCtrl', function( $scope,$http,$q,$location,$window,$routeParams,$modal, $log, $timeout) {
$scope.cellphonerating=[{"cellphone_info_id":"94","avg":"3.333","price":"4900"},
{"cellphone_info_id":"119","avg":"4","price":"4500"},
{"cellphone_info_id":"95","avg":"4.5","price":"5060"}];
});

car.js
var app3 = angular.module("carApp",['uiSlider','ui.bootstrap']);
app2.controller('carCtrl', function( $scope,$http,$q,$location,$window,$routeParams,$modal, $log, $timeout) {
$scope.carrating=[{"car_info_id":"94","avg":"3.333","price":"8900"},
{"car_info_id":"119","avg":"4","price":"900"},
{"car_info_id":"95","avg":"4.5","price":"2160"}];
});
```

For this I have different views and here problems begins for me

```
home.html
<div ng-app="HomeApp">
    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-2 pull-left" ng-repeat="h in homerating">
        <div class="panel-body" >
            <h2>{{h.price}}</h2>
             <input  class="check_count" type="checkbox" ng-checked="IsChecked"  ng-model="home.selected"   /> Add to Estimate<br>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
</div>
cellphone.html
<div ng-app="CellphoneApp">
    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-2 pull-left" ng-repeat="c in cellphonerating">
        <div class="panel-body" >
            <h2>{{c.price}}</h2>
             <input  class="check_count" type="checkbox" ng-checked="IsChecked"  ng-model="cellphone.selected"   /> Add to Estimate<br>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
</div>
car.html
<div ng-app="carrating">
    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-2 pull-left" ng-repeat="c in carrating">
        <div class="panel-body" >
            <h2>{{c.price}}</h2>
             <input  class="check_count" type="checkbox" ng-checked="IsChecked"  ng-model="car.selected"   /> Add to Estimate<br>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
</div>
```

What I want is whenever user clicks on add to estimate the price of clicked items should get added to total array and the items which are selected should be kept while going from car.html to cellphone.html or home.html. My major problems are

1: I am not getting how to write combined function to push selected items and in which controller?

2: Second is even if I add from home controller whenever I move to car.html page gets refresh because these are different modules so how to use cookies and session for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704064/how-do-i-combine-two-angularjs-apps-as-modules-of-a-main-app

Comment: i have seen that sagar If you understood that thing Then please let me know with my above example. I want to add each item to estimated list, please read my question and see if you can solve. by the way I tried all questions on stackoverflow, no luck so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a factory to persist and share data between multiple controllers
2. Use [routes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) vs. individual pages. Angular is a SPA (single page application) framework, `home.html` `cellphone.html` `car.html` should all be route templates in the same module, not stand alone applications.

While you *can* attach sub-modules as dependencies in a main module, for simplicity sake try combining all of your angular modules into a single module:

**main.js**

```
// app module
var app = angular.module("MainApp",['uiSlider','ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute']);

// routes
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  })
  .when('/cellphone', {
    templateUrl: 'cellphone.html',
    controller: 'CellphoneCtrl'
  })
  .when('/car', {
    templateUrl: 'car.html',
    controller: 'carCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
});

// home controller
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function( $scope,$http,$q,$location,$window,$routeParams,$modal, $log, $timeout) {
$scope.homerating=[{"home_info_id":"94","avg":"3","price":"4900"},
                   {"home_info_id":"119","avg":"4","price":"200"},
                   {"home_info_id":"95","avg":"4.5","price":"500"}];
});

// cell phone controller
app.controller('CellphoneCtrl', function( $scope,$http,$q,$location,$window,$routeParams,$modal, $log, $timeout) {
$scope.cellphonerating=[{"cellphone_info_id":"94","avg":"3.333","price":"4900"},
{"cellphone_info_id":"119","avg":"4","price":"4500"},
{"cellphone_info_id":"95","avg":"4.5","price":"5060"}];
});

// car controller
app.controller('carCtrl', function( $scope,$http,$q,$location,$window,$routeParams,$modal, $log, $timeout) {
$scope.carrating=[{"car_info_id":"94","avg":"3.333","price":"8900"},
{"car_info_id":"119","avg":"4","price":"900"},
{"car_info_id":"95","avg":"4.5","price":"2160"}];
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="MainApp">
  <head>...</head>
  <body>

    <!-- this is where the views (home/cell/car.html) will populate -->
    <div ng-view></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**update**

Based on your comments, maybe look into [angular locker](https://github.com/tymondesigns/angular-locker). It uses local/session storage vs cookies, but that's probably a plus. I think the entries are namespaced by module name, so you might need some extra configuration or module renaming, but it should allow your data to survive a full page change

Comment: Hello thanks for reply but you didnt understood my problem, I have given above example that not doesnt means my app is small, I have many works to do in each module, I cant combine or write them in single module. by the way I know usage of routes each of my module has 9 to 8 routes for each module, So do you want me to add every route every controller in single page?? That will be too risky. Please let me know how to combine angular modules taking above example which I have given, I need to calculate estimated price.

Comment: The main thing I need to keep items which are added in estimated list just like cart.

Comment: Sorry to say please dont provide such answers so that others will think you have answered this questions. I am telling you still you have not understood my problem, Please read carefully. 
1:I have 3 modules which cant be combined into main.js
2:I need working jsfiddle to estimate the price of checked items just like cart.