# Angular js : accessing one application inside another

Tags: angularjs, web-applications

I have two angular js web project deployed in my tomcat webapps folder. Now I want to merge them. The current folder structure is :

Webapps-

/-App1

/-App2

Both project have there own app.js,state providers and complete other application components.
I want to load page from App1, on the click of button in App2.

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704064/how-do-i-combine-two-angularjs-apps-as-modules-of-a-main-app), [This as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342603/how-to-run-two-separate-angular-js-apps-in-the-same-page)